# Django admin.E110 Error - The value of 'list_display_links' must be a list, a tuple, or None

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-admin, django-views

Just upgrade my app to Django 1.9.1 and am now getting an `admin.E110` error.  I've searched but can't figure out what the correction is.  I was missing trailing commas, but after adding them, it was still broken.  Below is some of the code, if you could please take a look.  Thank you in advance.

**admin.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from adminsortable2.admin import SortableAdminMixin
from .models import Listing


class ListingAdmin(SortableAdminMixin, admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['title', 'listing_name', 'location_type', 'featured_choices', 'status_choices', ]
    search_fields = ['title', 'listing_name', ]
    pass


admin.site.register(Listing, ListingAdmin)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's referring to a different property called [list_display_links](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display_links). I think if you just set it to None your error will go away, but take a look at those docs and you may want to use it.

Comment: oh and also, you don't need those trailing commas (which you might have known/guessed), only need it for a tuple with 1 item.

Comment: Thank you!!  `list_display_links = None` didn't work for me, but `list_display_list = ('title', 'listing_name', ...)` did work.  I also changed all the `[ ]` to `( )` for consistency.